# What is transitivity property of digraph?

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics, directed-acyclic-graphs, transitivity, poset

I'm studying discrete structures following the MIT lecture (Mathematics for Computer Science). In the book, the definition of transitivity is as follow:

[image: Definition of Transitivity]

Then the book says the graph in Figure 7.8 below **does not** satisfy the transitivity property:

[image: Converting DAG to Poset]
[image: Explanation for Figure 7.8 & 7.9]

But I think it is already transitive in Figure 7.8 as v2 -> v3 and v3 -> v4, then v2 -> v4.

Would anybody help me understand what I am missing here? Thank you so so so much in advance!!!

- All the pictures are from [the course note](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Only this element triplet (v2,v3,v4) is transitive. However, for a graph to satisfy the transitivity property, all triplet such that `vi -> vj && vj ->vk` needs to satisfy `vi -> vk`, which is not the case for (v1, v2, v3).

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé Oh now I understood! Thank you!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I am happy to delete this question but I thought it was programming related. Please let me know if I need to take it down.

Answer (score 1):

The **first figure is not a transitive relation** but **figure 7.8 is a transitive relation**.

The first Figure is not transitive since we have v1-->v2 and v2-->v3 but we don't have
 v1-->v3
But Figure 7.8 shows us how to change the first figure to make a transitive relation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but you are repeating what the textbook says. The reason I was confused was that I missed that all the pairs of vertices vi and vk with the relationship (vi-->vj-->vk) must have vi-->vk to satisfy the transitivity property. Gilles-PhilippePaillé is nicely explaining this above!